# Itext multiple signatures

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature

I have to sign a pdf with multiple signatures. This is not done at the same time. 
So A signs the document and after 2 days, B signs the document and so on...

As stated in the Manning iText in Action and following code examples found on the web, to add a signature on a document which already contains signature(s), I just have to add two parameters when creating the signature:

```
stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(this.pdfReader,
                    workingBaos, PdfWriter.VERSION_1_7, null, true);
```

null because I don't want to use a temporary file and true, to use the append mode and create a new revision.

The thing is that when I open the pdf, Acrobat Reader says that only the last signature is valid. The previous signatures are all invalid.
When I verify the pdf with iText, there is no problem.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Why, HowHigH, didn't you 'accept' nor 'upvote' this (perfect) answer from Bruno?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm the author of the book you're referring to.
IMO the part about digital signatures in the book is too short, but the publisher wanted to keep the number of pages under 500 (and I managed to convince him to add about a 100 more).

If you want to add multiple signatures, please read this white paper: http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures
This white paper is still under construction, but you can already find the code you need in the sections about 'signing documents in a workflow'.

For the sake of completeness: if you add an additional signature, you should create an instance of `PdfStamper` in *append mode*.

Update: when you say that iText verifies the PDF, you probably mean that iText tells you that the second signature is valid. I don't think iText can see the initial signature. If it does, let me know, and I'll look into it.

Comment: Look at the code snippet, append mode is already used. Dank u wel voor het digitalsignatures document. I check all the signatures with AcroFields af = signedDocumentReader.getAcroFields();
  List<String> names = af.getSignatureNames(); and for each signature, a check is done

Comment: Maybe you're breaking the MDP settings; see chapter 5 of the white paper.

Comment: My doubt is... is there any problem in ALWAYS creating PdfStamper in append mode, even for the first signature?

Comment: No, there is no problem in that. In case you would have a follow-up question: "what is the difference?" When you use append mode, the original PDF file remains unaltered. Removing the bytes with the signature at the end of the file, results in the original file. When you don't use append mode, the signature is merged into the original file and you can't restore the original bytes anymore.

Answer (score 3):

To make signature for document that already has a signature, you need to use:

```java
PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create), tmp,
                new StampingProperties().UseAppendMode());
```

Set: UseAppendMode

Comment: Your answer refers to iText 7. The question is about iText 5 or earlier.

Comment: PdfStamper stamper=PdfStamper.createSignature(new PdfReader(in), out, '\0', null, true);

Answer (score 2):

Check the certification level:

- NOT_CERTIFIED— creates an ordinary signature aka an approval or a recipient signature. A document can be signed for approval by one or more recipients.
- CERTIFIED_NO_CHANGES_ALLOWED— creates a certification signature aka an author signature. After the signature is applied, no changes to the document will be allowed.
- CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING— creates a certification signature for the author of the document. Other people can still fill out form fields or add approval signatures without invalidating the signature.
- CERTIFIED_FORM_FILLING_AND_ANNOTATIONS— creates a certification signature. Other people can still fill out form fields- or add approval signatures as well as annotations without invalidating the signature.

See [Digital Signatures for PDF](http://developers.itextpdf.com/books#digsig)

Try:

```
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
...
appearance.setCertificationLevel(PdfSignatureAppearance.NOT_CERTIFIED);
...
```